# Is there a way/tool to disable one of your secondary screens on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have 2 PC screens connected through DVI-D and my TV screen through HDMI, all set to extend the desktop range.
When I turn off my TV, my PC still thinks it is an active and connected screen.

Is there a way or utility to disable the screen in Windows?

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the `WinKey + P` function to update the display options on-the-fly?

Comment: Hi @Run5k I have. Unfortunately it doesn't allow me to just disable 1 of the added displays.

Comment: Have you tried changing the options in graphic card properties. (Right Click on your desktop -> Graphic Properties). Usually, there is an option to handle connected displays from there.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKumar thanks for the comment. I know it's possible there, but if possible I would like to make the process of enabling/disabling a secondary screen easier, by using a hotkey for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a nice function using the software [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) which you can download for free.

After installing the software, create 2 Monitor profiles (one with and one without the additional screen) and set up a hotkey for each profile.

Now you can hotkey between disabling or enabling the screen.

Comment: That's good to hear!  Please ensure that you return after the 2-day waiting period and mark your own suggestion as the accepted answer.

Comment: Is this functionality actually supported in the free version? According to https://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/, `Save Monitor Profiles for easy configuration later` is a paid feature.